# How do I convert between numeric types?

Tags: casting, type-conversion, rust

I want to convert a `u8` to an `i32`. I used to do:

```
use std::num::ToPrimitive;

fn main () {

    // ...
    // Other code
    // ...

    let int32 : i32 = u8Value.to_i32().unwrap();
}
```

This code does not compile in the recent nightlies.  It complains that the ToPrimitive trait is unstable and will likely be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `as` to cast numeric types:

```
fn main () {
    let u8_value: u8 = 42;
    let i32_value: i32 = u8_value as i32;
}
```

Comment: Ugh... I've found my problem.  I was trying to cast a &u8 instead of u8 which is why "as" never worked for me.  I was casting an iterator instead of a primitive.